# Ling-to-SQL Compiler Error When Creating Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-7, dictionary

I'm trying to develop a simple WP7 database app which uses Linq2SQL to query the database, but today I managed to received an internal compiler error :(

A simplified version of my query is below (`Results` is a class which holds my search results data):

```
var query =
(
  from x in MyTable
  join y in MyOtherTable on x.Key equals y.Key
  where SqlMethods.Like(x.Field, "%" + searchTerm + "%")
  select new Results
  {
    MyResultField = new Dictionary<MyEnum,string>()
    {
      { MyEnum.Value, x.Field },
      { MyEnum.OtherValue, y.Field }
    },
    ...
  }
);
```

However, trying to create a new `Dictionary` like this results in a raft of compiler errors, even though IntelliSense doesn't object. I've searched around, but I'm not sure how to achieve a similar result without trying to create a `Dictionary` at this point.

Any ideas for a hopeless newbie?! Many thanks in advance!

**Update**

Sorry, I forgot to include the compiler errors. Apart from #6, they're gibberish to me, but if it helps ...

```
# Error 1   Internal Compiler Error: stage 'BEGIN'  MyProject
# Error 2   Internal Compiler Error: stage 'EMIT'   MyProject
# Error 3   Internal Compiler Error: stage 'COMPILE'    MyProject
# Error 4   Internal Compiler Error: stage 'COMPILE'    C:\...\ViewModel.cs MyProject
# Error 5   Internal Compiler Error: stage 'COMPILE' symbol '<global namespace>'    C:\...\ViewModel.cs MyProject
# Error 6   Internal Compiler Error (0xc0000005 at address 681AB648): likely culprit is 'BIND'.
# An internal error has occurred in the compiler. To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed below. Locations at the top of the list are closer to the point at which the internal error occurred. Errors such as this can be reported to Microsoft by using the /errorreport option.
#   MyProject
# Error 7   Internal Compiler Error: stage 'COMPILE' symbol 'ChineseClassmate'  C:\...\ViewModel.cs 12  11  MyProject
# Error 8   Internal Compiler Error: stage 'COMPILE' symbol 'ChineseClassmate.MyProject'    C:\...\ViewModel.cs 12  11  MyProject
# Error 9   Internal Compiler Error: stage 'COMPILE' symbol 'ChineseClassmate.MyProject.ViewModel'  C:\...\ViewModel.cs 12  11  MyProject
# Error 10  Internal Compiler Error: stage 'COMPILE' symbol 'MyProject.ViewModel.MyProjectViewModel'    C:\...\ViewModel.cs 17  15  MyProject
# Error 11  Internal Compiler Error: stage 'COMPILE' symbol 'MyProject.ViewModel.MyProjectViewModel.SearchDatabase(string)' C:\...\ViewModel.cs 57  15  MyProject
# Error 12  Internal Compiler Error: stage 'COMPILE' symbol 'MyProject.ViewModel.MyProjectViewModel.SearchDatabase(string)' C:\...\ViewModel.cs 57  15  MyProject
# Error 13  Internal Compiler Error: stage 'COMPILE' symbol 'MyProject.ViewModel.MyProjectViewModel.SearchDatabase(string)' C:\...\ViewModel.cs 57  15  MyProject
# Error 14  Internal Compiler Error: stage 'BIND' symbol 'MyProject.ViewModel.MyProjectViewModel.SearchDatabase(string)'    C:\...\ViewModel.cs 57  15  MyProject
```

Comment: "An internal compiler error". "A raft of compiler errors". It's going to be really tricky for anybody to diagnose your problem unless you tell us *exactly* what those compiler errors are!

Comment: Sorry Luke, you're right! I've added the errors above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this. It must be able to translate this call into valid sql and using new objects in there as such I believe will cause a failure as that is not convertible to run all on the db side. You must get your results AND THEN convert to a dictionary (.ToDictionary())

Comment: Thanks Adam, I didn't think of that before, but I can see that it makes sense. I'll work on this different approach now.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit odd to create a dictionary for each row and have each dictionary only have the same two keys. You're better off modifying the `Results` to just have two fields like so:

```
var query =
    from x in MyTable
    join y in MyOtherTable on x.Key equals y.Key
    where SqlMethods.Like(x.Field, "%" + searchTerm + "%")
    select new Results
    {
        MyEnumValue = x.Field,
        MyEnumOtherValue = y.Field
        ...
    };
```

If you desperately have to have a dictionary there then maybe return the values in an anonymous type, then, after forcing the query execution with something like `.ToArray()`, you can create your `Results` objects with the existing dictionary code.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Enigmativity! This approach is definitely simpler and smoother, I was just using a `Dictionary` because the `Results` class helps me to set various other properties depending on the values it's provided. Anyway, thanks for your time, I'll definitely remember this for the future.